# Grant View Server State - is it possible for a none SA user to have in Azure SQL?

Tags: permissions, security, dmv, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to set up some scheduled jobs which will collect some server stats, using system DMV's in SQL Server Azure. 
If a none SA users uses 'sys.dm_os_schedulers', they get an error (below), query works fine for server admin.

***VIEW SERVER STATE permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'***

The user is a  member of DBManager Role in the MasterDB, and they are a member of the db_owner role in User DB, and have added VIEW DATABASE STATE in user db.

I've attempted to 'GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE to [user]' in Master DB, using the server admin account (set up via portal on initial database creation). However, this errors :-

***Grantor does not have GRANT permission.***

Is it possible to grant this? (which is what every post I've seen says), or how do I do it with the Server Admin account?

Answer (score 1):

`GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE` is not supported in Azure SQL Database.

[GRANT Server Permissions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-server-permissions-transact-sql)

In order to use `sys.dm_os_schedulers` you need:

> On SQL Database Premium Tiers, requires the VIEW DATABASE STATE
>   permission in the database. On SQL Database Standard and Basic Tiers,
>   requires the Server admin or an Azure Active Directory admin account.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-schedulers-transact-sql

While testing this I also could not grant `VIEW DATABASE STATE` to a user in master database using SA account.

I grant `VIEW DATABASE STATE` to the user database using SA account.  Then run `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_schedulers` in the context of user database. I was able to get result set.

Comment: The DB is a Premium P2, so I've added VIEW DATABASE STATE in USER db as I've mentioned in the question. The account still can't access 'sys.dm_os_schedulers'. Does it require 'VIEW DATABASE STATE' in Master? if so, it's back to my original question, as this errors as **'Grantor does not have GRANT permission'** when I try and GRANT with the Server admin account.

Comment: Updated my answer.  Please let me know if you were able replicate what I did.